# Posts not responsive, everything else is - Genesis Framework

Tags: html, css, responsive, genesis

mysteriously since yesterday the responsiveness of [one post](http://vagabondingmind.ch/diy-shampoo-mit-kernseife/) doesn't work anymore with Chrome. Narrowing the window makes only few pictures adjust their size, while the main picture and text remain the same (too big).

With Firefox none of them are responsive. It also changed the spacing on the left and on the right. But only when a post is viewed. Not the Homepage, nor Pages.

This is my website: http://vagabondingmind.ch/

The only things I did recently was signing up for Feedburner/Feedly and add a widget to the sidebar on the right.

The Media Queries are still the same as before. I am using Genesis Framework 2.3.1 with the Genesis Sample Child Theme.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: what happens if you disable the sidebar widget?

Comment: Nothing, stays the same. It's just a text-widget (the very last) with some HTML code inside. @SimonHänisch

Comment: After using the dev tools to delete nodes/elements, I found out that the page becomes responsive again when removing the `figure` elements, because they have a `style="width: 1000px"` applied.

Comment: worked out well, thank you so much! :) @SimonHänisch